# Eclipse highlights everything as an error when building with ant

Tags: eclipse, ant

I am using ant to do builds and outputting to the same file that eclipse outputs .class files into so that I can test easily using the eclipse console. However, once I do this eclipse says pretty much every line of my code is an error as it cannot 'resolve x to a type'. Does anyone know of a way to fix this? Refreshing the project doesn't seem to help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a refresh followed by clean build in eclipse. If it doesn't take the first time, do those steps once more.

I would not recommend having Eclipse and ant output to the same directory.

Comment: Maven builds sometimes will do this also.  Clean and rebuild from eclipse will fix the issue most times.  As Konstantin stated keep your output folder separate will help a lot.  you can always have Ant as a build step in your project but it is not perfect and will still do this from time to time.